# C exit from infinite loop on keypress

Tags: c, infinite-loop, getch

How can I exit from an infinite loop, when a key is pressed?
Currently I'm using getch, but it will start blocking my loop as soon, as there is no more input to read.

Comment: You used to be able to use `while(!kbhit())`, but this is prolly OS dependent.  You might want to have a look at http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html, depending on your os

Comment: Check out GetAsyncKeyState Function if you are using Windows.

Comment: kbhit() may be OS-dependent, but it is declared in conio.h, just like getch(). So if he/she uses getch(), he/she should have kbhit() too.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `getch()` from `conio.h` anyway, try to use `kbhit()` instead. Note that both `getch()` and `kbhit()` - `conio.h`, in fact - are not standard C.

Comment: Yes, conio.h is not standard because they are dependent on the OS that is been used.

Comment: Not every implementation of C has a conio.h at all, although many try to provide one, these days. How or if they are implemented depends on the platform, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

The function `kbhit()` from `conio.h` returns non-zero value if any key is pressed but it does not block like `getch()`. Now, this is obviously not standard. But as you are already using `getch()` from `conio.h`, I think your compiler has this.

```
if (kbhit()) {
    // keyboard pressed
}
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h),

> conio.h is a C header file used in old MS-DOS compilers to create text user interfaces. It is not described in The C Programming Language book, and it is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it required by POSIX.
>
> Most C compilers that target DOS, Windows 3.x, Phar Lap, DOSX, OS/2, or Win32[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) have this header and supply the associated library functions in the default C library. Most C compilers that target UNIX and Linux do not have this header and do not supply the library functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use non-standard, non-blocking way and yet graceful exit. Use signals and **Ctrl+C** with user provided signal handler to clean up. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Signal Handler for SIGINT */
void sigint_handler(int sig_num)
{
    /* Reset handler to catch SIGINT next time.
       Refer http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal */
    printf("\n User provided signal handler for Ctrl+C \n");

    /* Do a graceful cleanup of the program like: free memory/resources/etc and exit */
    exit(0);
}

int main ()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    /* Infinite loop */
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Inside program logic loop\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Include stdlib.h to execute exit function
int char ch;
int i;

clrscr();
void main(){

printf("Print 1 to 5 again and again");
while(1){
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)

     printf("\n%d",i);

    ch=getch();
    if(ch=='Q')// Q for Quit
     exit(0);

    }//while loop ends here

    getch();
    }
```