# How to interrupt a C++ program

Tags: c++

This is the gist the program :

```
while(true)
{
//bunch of codes that gets data from port ,
//if there is no data it waits here .

}
```

i am using linux , is there any inbuilt support for keypresses like Ctrl+C . I can catch that using   `signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);` but Ctrl+C has some problem as it gives errors .

i want to get out of this loop on keypress , is this possible ? 
If yes , how to do it .

Comment: `break` well get you out the loop. to get the key, you well probably need a thread.

Comment: Which OS? On Windows, checking with `GetAsyncKeyState` would humbly suffice for a specific key.

Comment: "if there is no data it waits here" I think you mean *spins* here, unless your port-read is blocking.

Comment: it;s blocking , it stops there .

Comment: i am using linux , is there any inbuilt support for keypresses like Ctrl+C . I can catch that using   **signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);** but Ctrl+C has some problem it gives errors .

Comment: On Linux, you can use NCurses. This has been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4028974/856199

Comment: @rajat Remember than when you use ncurses in your program, you have to link the ncurses library when you build it. Simply add `-lncurses` at the end of your g++ command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can signal an interupt

```
      #include <csignal>

      raise(SIGINT);
```

or

```
     raise(SIGABRT);
```

Comment: which signal it will catch , Ctrl+C ? Any-others ?

Comment: Ctrl+C..I would suggest you to refer this link for signal handling:- http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_39.html Hope it works!!1

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!_kbhit()){
    // do stuff here.
}
```

Works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The function that can terminate your program is [`exit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/).

To input a premature termination of your cicle you can use [`break`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#jump_statements).

If you are willing to use some C oriented solution i suggest to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731317/c-exit-from-infinite-loop-on-keypress).

For something strictly related to linux you probably should refer to the [ncurses library in combination with the exit function](http://www.google.com/#q=c+++exit%28%29+ncurses&oq=c+++exit%28%29+ncurses).

Also do not assume that a particular key combination is equal to a termination, many terminals are not real terminals but emulators, and many emulators are customizable, by the OS creator and by the user.