# Exiting loop at anytime in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit a loop at anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540995/exit-a-loop-at-anytime)

Sorry but I have another problem. If I change 'time_t end = time(0) + 1;' to 'time_t end = time(0) + 5;'... Then my program will not exit the loop straight away but exits after 5 seconds. How can I change it to exit the loop straight away? Let's say if it were to be a minute, cause I'm creating a program, a parking meter where you can exit the loop anytime to claim for refunds. Reference to the code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int b=0, i;
    int seconds;
    printf("\nEnter number of seconds : ");
    scanf("%d", &seconds);
    while (b==0)
    {
        b=kbhit();
        for(i=1;i<=seconds;i++)
        {
            while (b==0)
            {
                b=kbhit();
                time_t end = time(0) + 5; //5 seconds delay.
                while(time(0) < end)
                {
                    b=kbhit();
                }
                seconds -= 5;
                printf("Number of seconds left : %d\n", seconds);
                b=kbhit();  
            }
        }
        if(seconds == 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        b=kbhit();
    }
    printf("Number of remaining seconds left : %d\n", seconds);
}
```

Comment: You can use `break` to exit a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `break` is a better solution to exit the loop

Comment: If that really answered your question plz dont forget to accept it so that it could help others.