# Several statements while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, logical-operators

I'm trying to put another statement to end the while-loop with logical AND:

```
while ( (character != '\n') && ( i < 10 ) )
```

...the extra +10:th letters does not get stored in the array. **But** I can still type in input until pressing ENTER / '\n' .

What am I doing wrong? What happens with the 'extra input'?

This is the code:

```
char character;
char buffer[81];
int i = 0;

do
{
    character = getchar();
    buffer[i] = character;
    ++i;
} while ( (character != '\n') && (i < 10) );

buffer[i-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: You are changing the 10th character to `\0` in line `buffer[i-1] = '\0'`. You meant `buffer[i]` perhaps. When the loop stops, i becomes 10 and you are setting `\0` to `buffer[9]`.

Comment: You need to check that i < sizeof(buffer) before you use it to reference [i].

Comment: @SPlatten That's not needed since the loop stops when i is 10 and the buffers size is 81.

Comment: @kuro Ah whups. 10 was a "test limit" but same rule applies. Thanks!  I'll skip the `do`- loop so `\n`never gets included.

Comment: @Splatten Thank you! `sizeof()` is just what I needed. :D

Comment: @klutt, it is needed because its a do { } while loop and the test for i is not until after it has been referenced.

Comment: @SPlatten The above code has zero chance of reading outside the buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `getchar` does not read directly from the keyboard. It reads from `stdin`. And in most cases what you have written on the keyboard will not end up in `stdin` until you press enter. This behavior is outside your control and is determined by the terminal you are using.

So your code basically works, except that you should change `buffer[i-1]` to `buffer[i]`. If you want to detect keypresses directly, then you will need different methods. There are no good functions in the standard library to do this, but here is an answer that gives you two options. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349652/6699433

Comment: Yes ok! don't really need it, but I was scared they ended up in some infinite loop/stack/array. 
10 was a "test limit", but same rule apply. Thanks a lot!  :D

Answer (score 2):

When the do-while loop stops, `i` becomes 10 in your case. Let's say your input was `0123456789`. The input does not contain `\n` so `buffer[9]` becomes `'9'`. Now, after that you are assigning `buffer[i - 1]` to `\0` and `buffer[9]` becomes `\0`.

You want `buffer[i] = '\0'`. Also, do not forget to check that `i` does not cross the buffer size.

Comment: Ah yes, I see! If I end with *enter* `\n` will be included and if I "extend" the limit <10 it won't be! Maybe I should just skip starting with a `do` loop .